# Blank Vector Selection Dropdown in QGIS GRASS Plugin

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis

I realise there are some issues which getting vectors into the GRASS module in QGIS, but is the behaviour i am getting expected?

I have loaded the vector shapefile via GRASS, closed G and reopened the mapset in QGIS, GRASS TOOLS. I can find the vector in Browser tab, but when I launch v.rast.stats I cannot select a vector. The vector selection drop down remains blank.

Is this the behavious people are seeing, or is it a different problem to that which is already documented?
Trouble is, it used to work a few months ago on 1.6 and the 1.7 trunk no problems.

Comment: good news for the grass plugin... Quote from qgis developer forum - Martin "I am going to provide daily build packages for GRASS 6.4, 6.5 and 7.0
for OSGeo4W within few next days." http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Doh!!

I found I have to add the vector to the canvas, 
somehow it is already displaying so I think the GRASS plugin could see it?? Anyways fixed now.

Comment: Yes, that's the case for all GRASS plugin functions.